# Винительный падеж - косвенный или прямой, и почему

Tags: числительные, родительный-падеж, винительный-падеж

Как говорит нам Грамота.ру

> Числительные два, три, четыре (а также составные числительные, оканчивающиеся на два, три, четыре, например двадцать два) в именительном падеже сочетаются с существительным в форме родительного падежа и единственного числа, например: двадцать два стола, тридцать три несчастья, пятьдесят четыре человека. Числительные пять, шесть, семь, восемь, девять и т. д. и составные числительные, оканчивающиеся на пять, шесть, семь, восемь и т. д., согласуются с существительным, стоящим в форме родительного падежа множественного числа, например: сорок восемь преступников. Однако в косвенных падежах согласование выравнивается: р. п. – двух столов, пяти столов, д. п. – двум столам, пяти столам.

Также на википедии нашел такую информацию

> Выделяют прямой падеж (именительный и иногда также винительный) и косвенные падежи (остальные).

Таким образом в предложениях

> Я вышел из комнаты на три минуты. Она жила в Москве два года. Саша купил четире стула.

существительные использованы в родительном падеже единственного числа.

Помогите найти информацию про "косвенность" или "прямость" винительного падежа, и чем он заслужил такое особенное положение. Спасибо!

Comment: Traditionally, in nominative languages, an oblique case (*косвенный падеж*) is any case you can't put a grammatical subject in. Does the Wikipedia article refer to any reputable source claiming accusative being a direct case?

Comment: http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200800104

Answer (score 1):

Прямой падеж это когда форма совпадает с именительным падежом, а косвенный когда не совпадает.  Существительные 3-го склонения (мышь, рожь) и многие существительные второго склонения (шкаф, поле) имеют одну и ту же форму в винительном падеже, что и в именительном. Этот случай называется прямым падежом. Все остальные случаи косвенные.

http://nashol.com/2011060955536/tablica-padejei-russkogo-yazika.html

> Выделяют прямой падеж (именительный и иногда также винительный) и косвенные падежи (остальные). Эта терминология связана с античным представлением о «склонении» (declinatio) как «отклонениях», «отпадениях» от правильной, «прямой» формы слова

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, винительный падеж - косвенный. Но для неодушевленных предметов в русском для него используется форма, идентичная именительному падежу. В этом случае его можно (с натяжкой) назвать прямым. Например:

> Я вижу утку. (Одуш. в.п. от "утка")

но

> Я вижу шкаф. (Неодуш. в.п. = и.п. "шкаф")

Грамматическая зависимость тут все равно косвенная, но форма (в какой-то мере случайно) прамая.

Comment: This is only true for declensions II and III and plural forms. Declension I nouns differ in nominative, genitive and accusative cases in singular, regardless of animacy: *лампа // нет лампы // вижу лампу; утка // нет утки // вижу утку*